# Open a new TextBox when Checkbox is checked Javascript

Tags: javascript

On check of a check box I would like a box of text to open where someone could add further information
So far I have the html for it, and I had this for the javascript:

```
function showDiv() {
var checked=document.getElementById("checkbox");
if (checked.checked == true) {
```

I am stuck as where to move on from here
I am sure it is very simple but from just googling and searching on here I cannot find a solution

Comment: do you mean making a textbox visible?

Comment: more or less, I just want it so where when I person clicks the box it opens a box for text.  Like if the label for the checkbox was do you have your own website? then upon clicking it a new box would open prompting them to put in their website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script>
    function showDiv(obj) {
    debugger
    if (obj.checked) {
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="text_box"/>';
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = '';
        }
    }
</script>
  Check Me<input type="checkbox" onchange="showDiv(this)"/>
<div id="content">

</div>
```

Javascript code is above

Comment: this is great thanks, is there anyway to label the textbox though?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    function showDiv(obj) {
        if ($(obj).is(":checked")) {
            $('#content').append('<input type="text" id="text_box"/>');
        }
        else {
            $('#text_box').remove();
        }
    }
</script>
<div id="content">
    Check Me<input type="checkbox" onchange="showDiv(this)"/>
</div>
```

Comment: The original question does not mention jQuery in any way, so why are you trying to answer with jQuery?